# SyntaxError: unterminated string literal var address = "

Tags: javascript, php, string, variables, syntax-error

I've this problem at the var address line, i think to have write all correctly or not?

```
<?php for ($i = 1; $i <= count($data); $i++) { ?>
  var address = "<?php echo $address[$i].','.$city[$i].','.$region[$i] ?>";
  alert(address);
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Is there a `"` in one of the PHP variables? There could also be an error in the code above this snippet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're generating javascript with php and the error you get comes from the javascript part, not php. I guess that one of your variables like `$address` contains something that isn't valid in js strings, like a newline. The best practice is to use `json_encode` to encode values for use in javascript:

```
var address = <?php echo json_encode($address[$i].','.$city[$i].','.$region[$i]) ?>;
```